# Convert hexadecimal to decimal from signed 2's complement, java

Tags: java

I want to convert an hexadecimal number to a decimal from signed 2's complement, like this: FFOC -> -64. I'm using java. I already know how to convert from hexadecimal to decimal and binary but not from signed 2's. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution:

```
String ss = new BigInteger(rssi, 16).toString(2);
        String aux = ss.substring(8);
        int res;
        if(aux.charAt(0)=='0'){
            res = Integer.parseInt(aux,2);
        }
        else{
            String g = aux.substring(1);
            res = Integer.parseInt(g, 2) * (-1);

        }
```